# Loading exactly two modules in a particular position joomla

Tags: php, joomla, joomla3.2

I want to be able to assign multiple modules in a particular position but display only two of them at any given time in joomla. How do I be do that ?

Comment: What if I want to be able to randomize the selection of the modules assigned to a particular position.. through Code ?

Comment: This is not a feature that comes with Joomla. You might need to look for a 3rd party extension or write your own plugin

Comment: You would likely want to write your own module that loads all the modules assigned to a position that doesn't exist in your template (which Joomla allows). That module you create would then have the code to randomly select 2 modules and display them.

Comment: @DavidFritsch Thanks for that but I just found the solution from the doc.. Posting it as an answer now..

Comment: I'd love to see the answer!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After some research I found out that one can use the below code to do it.

```
$arrayofmoduleObj = JModuleHelper::getModules('position') // to get an array of module Object.
$options    = array('style' => 'chrome');
foreach($arrayofmoduleObj as $moduleObject){
    /* code to decide whether to print this module or not if yes    */
    echo JModuleHelper::renderModule($moduleObject,$options) //to render a module Object..
   else continue;
}
```